# I am making a rock, paper, scissors game and the values of the outputs are not all corect

Tags: javascript

I typed the statements and everything is working fine only when I try the console with the answer of rock. When I try to see other logs(paper or scissors) it gives me the output based on the first 3 if conditions(from the rock) and the others for some reason doesn't apply.

```js
//My "choice"// 
function playerPlay() {
  let Answer = prompt(`Do you choose Rock,Paper or Scissors ?`).toLowerCase();
  console.log(Answer);
}
playerPlay()
//Computer random choice//
function computerPlay() {
  computerPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
  if (computerPlay === 0) {
    console.log("rock");
  } else if (computerPlay === 1) {
    console.log("paper");
  } else if (computerPlay === 2) {
    console.log("scissors");
  }
}
computerPlay()

//The conditions for the game//

function rules() {
  if (Answer = "rock" && computerPlay === 0) {
    return ("Draw");
  } else if (Answer = "rock" && computerPlay === 1) {
    return ("You lost");
  } else if (Answer = "rock" && computerPlay === 2) {
    return ("You won");
  }

  if (Answer = "paper" && computerPlay1 === 0) {
    return ("You Won!");
  } else if (Answer = "paper" && computerPlay === 1) {
    return ("Draw");
  } else if (Answer = "paper" && computerPlay === 2) {
    return ("You Lost!");

  }
  if (Answer = "scissors" && computerPlay === 0) {
    return ("You Lost!")
  } else if (Answer = "scissors" && computerPlay === 1) {
    return ("You Won!");

  } else if (Answer = "scissors" && computerPlay === 2) {
    return ("Draw!");

  }
}
rules()
```

In the Image you can see that paper with paper is supposed to be a tie but the output actually is "You lost!"

[image]

Comment: in the function rules you are using a single equal sign which resets the variable. Replace it with a double equal sign. Do it everywhere in the function. like this: Answer == 'rock'

Comment: This is a bit unrelated to the question, but you should use switch statements instead of an if else chain in the `computerPlay()` function.

Comment: If I do that the console tells me that the Answer is not defined

Comment: I tried to use if then switch then while but I then i returned to if

Comment: Where did you declare `Answer`?  If you declare a variable inside a function using `let`, it cannot be accessed outside of that function.

Comment: Yea.. it is in the function scope (playerplay)

Answer (score 2):

`answer = "..."` 
should be `answer == "..."` in your if statements.
`=` is used for assignment not for checking equality

You are defining the answer variable inside of your function using `let`. This means that the `answer` is only defined within the scope of the function and is not a global variable. Instead you should have it return answer, and instead of calling `playerPlay()` you should do `answer = playerPlay()`

The same issue exists with your computer play function. Your rules function returns the answer but nothing prints it out.

Comment: If I do that the console tells me that the Answer is not defined,

Comment: @Axel read my update. You have multiple issues here.

Comment: Now my code works well. I modified the Answer, instead of one = i put two(==) and I deleted the function and I just gave a value to Answer(
        let Answer = prompt(`Do you choose Rock,Paper or Scissors ?`).toLowerCase();)
And about the computer play function, I invoke the function so it gaves me the value in  the console.